# Python winshell.shortcut function is not working properly in Exe file

Tags: python, server, pyinstaller

-- Python 3.11.5, PyQt5 5.15.9, winshell 0.6

Hi. I'm currently working on making exe file using Pyqt5, Pyinstaller.

Now I have a trouble generating shortcut file.

My script runs perfectly when initialized through pycharm,
while it stops without any error message when it run using exe file generated by pyinstaller. More specifically, exe file stops if the target folder is in server. Below are the cases that might be considered. Please help solving this problem.

Case1 : Target Path(local), Shortcut Path(server)  -- runs well

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiBDS.png)

Case2 : Target Path(server), Shortcut Path(server)  -- Stops at "shortcut = ws.shortcut(target_path)"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEKad.png)

Case3 : Target Path(server), Shortcut Path(local)  -- Stops at "shortcut = ws.shortcut(target_path)"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ke7xw.png)

Here is my test script

```
import sys 
import os 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * 
from PyQt5.QtCore import * 
import winshell as ws

def my_exception_hook(exctype, value, traceback): print(exctype, value, traceback) sys._excepthook(exctype, value, traceback)

sys._excepthook = sys.excepthook sys.excepthook = my_exception_hook

class TEST_UI(QWidget): send_instance_signal = pyqtSignal('PyQt_PyObject')

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.setupUI()

def setupUI(self):
    self.setGeometry(200, 200, 200, 200)
    self.setWindowTitle('☆TEST☆')
    self.folder_Path_test = QLabel('\\\\10.10.10.11\\')
    self.folder_Path_test.setStyleSheet('font: 12px; color: green;')
    self.folder_Path_test.setMaximumWidth(600)
    self.folder_Path_test.setWordWrap(True)
    self.btn_test_path = QPushButton('Target Path')
    self.btn_test_path.clicked.connect(self.btn_test_path_change)

    self.rcv_folder_test = QLabel('\\\\10.10.10.11\\')
    self.rcv_folder_test.setStyleSheet('font: 12px; color: green;')
    self.rcv_folder_test.setMaximumWidth(600)
    self.rcv_folder_test.setWordWrap(True)
    self.btn_test_rcv_folder_path = QPushButton('Shortcut Path')
    self.btn_test_rcv_folder_path.clicked.connect(self.btn_test_path_change2)

    self.generate_shortcut_btn = QPushButton('Run')
    self.generate_shortcut_btn.clicked.connect(self.generate_shortcut)

    vbox = QVBoxLayout()
    vbox.addWidget(self.folder_Path_test)
    vbox.addWidget(self.btn_test_path)
    vbox.addWidget(self.rcv_folder_test)
    vbox.addWidget(self.btn_test_rcv_folder_path)
    vbox.addWidget(self.generate_shortcut_btn)

    self.setLayout(vbox)
    self.setMinimumSize(self.sizeHint())
    self.show()


def btn_test_path_change(self):
    folder_directory = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, 'Choose Folder', directory=(os.path.expanduser('~')+"\\Desktop"))
    self.folder_Path_test.setText(folder_directory.replace('/', '\\'))

def btn_test_path_change2(self):
    folder_directory = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, 'Choose Folder', directory=(os.path.expanduser('~')+"\\Desktop"))
    self.rcv_folder_test.setText(folder_directory.replace('/', '\\'))



def generate_shortcut(self):
    def Generate_SC(target_path, shortcut_path, file_name):
        print("1")
        try:
            if os.path.exists(target_path):
                print("2")
                print(target_path)
                print(shortcut_path)
                print(file_name)
                shortcut = ws.shortcut(target_path)
                print("3")
                shortcut.write(os.path.join(shortcut_path, file_name))
                print("4")
        except OSError as e:
            print(e)
    a=self.folder_Path_test.text()
    b=self.rcv_folder_test.text()
    c='test.lnk'
    Generate_SC(a,b,c)

if name == 'main':
 app = QApplication(sys.argv)
 ex = TEST_UI()
 sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I just want my exe file run well whoever use it